# Why my computer suddently shut down when am working on my VS2012EXPRESS

Tags: windows-7

I Notice when am coding,sometime my machine shutdown unexpectedly with the following errors: What causes this.

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033

Additional information about the problem:
BCCode: 116
BCP1:   8623B008
BCP2:   8F02D9B0
BCP3:   00000000
BCP4:   00000002
OS Version: 6_1_7601
Service Pack:   1_0
Product:    256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
C:\Windows\Minidump\013113-16192-01.dmp
C:\Users\ecomma\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-179276-0.sysdata.xml
```

Comment: The Bug Check Code (BCCode) indicated in your eventlog is 116.  Microsoft lists that as [Bug Check 0x116: VIDEO_TDR_ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557263(v=vs.85).aspx).  This could indicate an issue with your video drivers or even the graphics card hardware. Please [follow these troubleshooting steps](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Resolving-stop-blue-screen-errors-in-Windows-7) and update your question with any new information.

Comment: This is possibly not related to Visual Studio, you might just happen to spend more time in it than in other programs.